# Does a cron daemon drain a laptop battery significantly faster?

Tags: linux, laptop, battery, cron

I would like to run a small script every hour to change my wallpaper. Does running a standard cron daemon (like fcron, cronie) cost a disproportional amount of battery lifetime? I would not expect this, since there were probably smart people involved developing these programs, but I'd like to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

`Cron` daemon and light script like a wallpaper changer run once per hour will not have any notable effect on battery life. There might be notable effect only if you run intensive script very often.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any sources to prove your point or are you talking from experience?

Comment: I base this on experience. I tried looking for but could not find good source stating this clearly. Testing can be done with command like `top` or `htop` to observe how much resources `Cron` is using. You will find that CPU usage is minimal when compared to many other processes. This implies that its effect on battery life is also mimimal.